# Jquery slideshow using dynamic json output not working

Tags: jquery, css

Im trying to create a youtube video slide show  using 
http://www.aerowebstudio.net/codecanyon/jquery.slider/example_a_1.html

It works fine except when dynamically appending using json

Json part works fine and gives the desired output

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/?feed=true&json=true&callback=?',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        var posturl = "";
        var htmlcode = "";

        <!-- 
                    json parser code goes here

                -->            

          htmlcode +=  '<div><div class="caption"><a href="'+postUrl+'"><h4>'+posttitle+'</h4></div><img src="'+imageUrl+'" alt=""/></a> </div>';

            $(".slider").append(htmlcode);

    }
});
  });
```

Json output

```
<div class="slider">

<div> <!-- slide 1 -->
<div class="caption"><a href="http://localhost/exercitation-ullamco-laboris.html">
<h4>Exercitation ullamco laboris perspiciatis unde omnis iste voluptate</h4></a></div>

<a href="http://localhost/exercitation-ullamco-laboris.html">
<img alt="" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/wOUgRif7JRc/0.jpg"></a>
</div>


<div> <!-- slide 2 -->
<div class="caption"><a href="http://localhost/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur.html">
<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit incididing</h4></a></div>

<a href="http://localhost/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur.html">
<img alt="" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/K2ia36quNyo/0.jpg"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

and the slider function

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".slider").slideshow({
    width      : 580,
    height     : 400,
    pauseOnHover : false,
    transition : 'SwipeLeft'
    //['slideLeft', 'slideRight', 'slideTop', 'slideBottom']
  });

  $(".caption").fadeIn(500);

  // playing with events:

  $(".slider").bind("sliderChange", function(event, curSlide) {
    $(curSlide).children(".caption").hide();
  });

  $(".slider").bind("sliderTransitionFinishes", function(event, curSlide) {
    $(curSlide).children(".caption").fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

When the output is hardcoded it works but when doing it dynamically via json, it fails. It seems like already liked css styles are not applied to the output

Someone please help me to move forth. thanks

Comment: I guess you meant "already linked css styles are not applied to the output". Does this mean you are actually seeing anything but it looks all nasty and unstyled?

Comment: @Derija93,
yes it seems unstyled. is there any technique to append the output so that it should be visible in proper style & slide

Comment: It would seem as if you would need to re-instantiate the plugin for it to recognize dynamic content.

Comment: The problem can't be that previously linked stylesheets are not styling your elements. They always do for elements now and in future as long as they match the selector. Since hardcoded slides work fine, I agree with Ohgodwhy.

Comment: thanks all, would you please show an example how to do this. Im struck

Comment: try running your slider function on success of the ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your slider function in a named function:

```
function sliderIni(){
  $(".slider").slideshow({
    width      : 580,
    height     : 400,
    pauseOnHover : false,
    transition : 'SwipeLeft'
    //['slideLeft', 'slideRight', 'slideTop', 'slideBottom']
  });

  $(".caption").fadeIn(500);

  // playing with events:

  $(".slider").bind("sliderChange", function(event, curSlide) {
    $(curSlide).children(".caption").hide();
  });

  $(".slider").bind("sliderTransitionFinishes", function(event, curSlide) {
    $(curSlide).children(".caption").fadeIn(500);
  });
}
```

Then call it on success of your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/?feed=true&json=true&callback=?',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        var posturl = "";
        var htmlcode = "";

        <!-- 
                    json parser code goes here

                -->            

          htmlcode +=  '<div><div class="caption"><a href="'+postUrl+'"><h4>'+posttitle+'</h4></div><img src="'+imageUrl+'" alt=""/></a> </div>';

            $(".slider").append(htmlcode);
            sliderIni();

    }
});
```

Make sure you have defined `sliderIni()` before it is run. Try defining it before the AJAX function or failing that outside of `$(document).ready`

Comment: thanks dude, when running the function on ajax success it's wonderfully sliding!!! you really saved my head.